# No connection in docker with ports exposed and published

Tags: java, docker, sockets, mule, mule-component

I have some middleware running in a docker container.

When I run this middleware **on my host machine everything works fine**.

When I ran it on the **docker** container with all the necessary **ports exposed and published**:

Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 5672 15672 1337 1338 5556 3000
```

Docker-compose.yml

```
ports:
- "5672:5672"
- "15672:15672"
- "1337:1337"
- "1338:1338"
- "5556:5556"
- "3000:3000"
```

It’s weird because I have rabbitmq and mule in that image. Rabbit works well beacause I can access the management console and my mule app publish in it.

I have a flow, that with a quartz component publish in rabbitmq a keep alive each 30ms, and works well.

But I have other flow which receives information in an UDP inbound endpoint and publish that on a rabbitmq queue. **The inbound endpoind doesn´t receive anything, this endpoint listens in 0.0.0.0 and port 1338, and I am binding 1338:1338.**

So if I receive packages on my localhost:1338 in my host machine, the inbound endpoint should receive it no?

Also in other flow I have a j**ava client socket which gives me connection refeused.**

The strange thing is that nothing of this happens when I run this on my host machine, and in docker I have the ports exposed and published.

Thanks everyone

Comment: look into `docker inspect <container id>`

Comment: That's a lot of ports.  Is the single process running in the container listening on all of them?

Comment: The docker inspect seems good as in the definition of the docker-compose and dockerfile. And yes I am sure I am listening in all the ports I have checked it. Thanks.

Comment: The thing is that middleware running on the host machine give me no errors. And now in the docker container with all the ports I use linked with the host I get connection refused. May I need to do configure something more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to indicate docker it is udp protocol.

FROM:

```
-1338:1338
```

TO:

```
- 1338:1338/udp
```